# Oracle .NET appending M for ExecuteScalar int values. VS2019 reports only int in tooltip

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, visual-studio

I have an application that takes user created `COUNT(*)` query and does a `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` and notifies users based on the result.

This is utilizes both SQL and Oracle .NET adapters.

Using SQL adapters this code block runs as expected for returned int values:

```
var threshold = await command.ExecuteScalarAsync();
if (threshold is int?)
//Continue with int comparison logic
```

However, using Oracle adapters `if(threshold is int?)` returns `false`. If we look at the tooltips in VS2019 you would not know anything is wrong.

[image]

Clicking into the value you can see the actual issue is that Oracle returns an `M` on the value:

[image]

My issue is two-fold:

1. Why does .NET Oracle adapters append an `M` to the end of the values being returned from `ExecuteScalar`?
2. Why doesn't VS2019 show the true values in tooltips?

EDIT:
The following solves the coding issue:

```
var scalarResult = await cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync();
if (int.TryParse(scalarResult.ToString(), out int threshold))
```

Wish in the hover over tooltip it showed `0M` or the datatype of the zero without having to "edit" the value to see its "true value".

Comment: is it possible that for Oracle the ExecuteScalar of your query is a decimal and not an int? Usually you can write "decimal a = 12m;"...

Comment: If you run the count query directly in Oracle, does it returns a `Decimal` (which is what the M is signifying).  It's the Oracle adapter that's 'wrong' IMO.

Comment: If you look at the documentation for the Oracle adaptor, they cast the result to `int`, so I'm guessing MS found this issue too.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oracleclient.oraclecommand.executescalar?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Regarding 2.   VS2019 IS showing exactly the true value, it's just that YOU think it isn't.

Comment: It doesn't return a Decimal? I don't know of a case where Count() can return half a row. Though I admit I can't find any documentation stating the specific return value for the Oracle Adapter. Examples being cast to `int` notwithstanding because I can find just the same `.ToString()` examples as well.

Comment: This is because Oracle have no native `int` datatype and a calculated datatype for `count(*)` is `number` with no precision and scale (when you do `create table ... as select count(*) ... `, [for example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=87b2060b4f950f13ff631d0af70dbfe3)). According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/oracle-data-type-mappings?redirectedfrom=MSDN), it is mapped to Decimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is exactly as @astentx stated in your question.  Int is C#.  You want to reference Oracle.DataAccess.dll (or ManagedDataAccess) and use the appropriate data type from OracleDbType.  Since COUNT is only going to return an integer, INT32 or INT64 is probably the best option since there is no NUMBER type.

Even though the above should work, my preference is usually to pull numbers back into C# as strings to avoid the data conversion and then use MS libraries to convert them to numbers natively.  This does require that you lock down your user queries to either have the user define the data type returned or you programmatically lock it as always being a certain type, such as number in this case.

Comment: Ah, I see his documentation link. I still don't like how VS2019 doesn't immediately show something is "wrong" without clicking into the actual value.